# ViewModel Memory Leak - Getting Rid of a Circular Dependency

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have knockout.js child view models living in an `observableArray` that depend on an `observable` in their parent view model. The parent's `observable` is bound to a `select` drop-down, and the children need to know when that value changes.

I've passed the entire parent view model, just the `observable`, and also subscribed inside the parent to the `observable` in order to update the children "manually." All of these work for binding purposes.

The problem is if I then clear out the child `observableArray` to make room for new children, or simply replace the children with new children, the old children stick around in memory because they're still referenced by the reverse dependency set up by knockout.js.

I am open to either a different design pattern or a way to tell knockout to stop holding onto the dependencies. In another example I tried cleanNode() but that didn't seem to clean up these reverse dependencies.

Code:

```
function FamilyViewModel(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.children = ko.observableArray();
}

function ChildViewModel(firstName, lastName, selectedFamilyObservable) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(lastName);
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
    this.isSelected = ko.computed(function() {
        return selectedFamilyObservable().name == this.lastName();
    }, this);
}

function PageViewModel() {
    this.families = ko.observableArray([
            new FamilyViewModel("Smith"),
            new FamilyViewModel("Jones"),
            new FamilyViewModel("Brown")
            ]);
    this.selectedFamily = ko.observable();
    this.addChild = _.bind(function() {
        this.selectedFamily().children.push(new ChildViewModel("Frank", this.selectedFamily().name, this.selectedFamily));
    }, this);
    this.resetChildren = _.bind(function() {
        this.selectedFamily().children([]);
    }, this);
}

$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new PageViewModel());
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cygnl7/xhzkC/1/

Comment: First, you are using models as view models, which although it won't break your code, it is very confusing.  Check into the difference between a model and a view model in Knockout (their tutorials are very helpful) and you may see a problem in your own code.

Comment: Also, please add a more detailed description of your problem.  As it stands I don't get what the problem is and your fiddle has more than one problem, so I am not sure which is presenting the problem itself.

Comment: The problem I stated is that "the old children stick around in memory because they're still referenced by the reverse dependency". I could have made that stand out more. But the point is that the child model (yeah, I misnamed those as viewmodels) needs to use a value in the parent viewmodel for some of its calculations, and that ends up creating the reverse dependency which makes the child stick around forever which leads to ever-increasing memory usage.

Comment: Im curious what you mean he has named the model as a viewmodel? Child and family-ViewModel are both viewmodels and the name is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34ZjB/) solution referenced earlier.

The crux of your problem is that you want to not only keep track of the currently selected family (`.selectedFamily`) but that you also want each family to know if they're selected.  I think the simplest solution is to subscribe to `selectedFamily` and monitor its value before it changes and after it changes to set a family's `isSelected` value.  I like this approach because there's no need to loop through the families array in order to do this.

```
self.selectedFamily = ko.observable();
self.selectedFamily.subscribe(function (oldValue) {
    if (oldValue) {
        oldValue.isSelected(false);
    }
}, null, 'beforeChange');
self.selectedFamily.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
       newValue.isSelected(true);
    }
});
```

Subscriptions default functionality passes in the new value *after* the value has already changed.  Here you'll have access to the newly selected family and you can set its `isSelected` property to true.  But subscriptions have two built in *topics* that get called by default.  The first is the 'change' topic, that we just discussed, and the other is 'beforeChange'.  This gets called before the value changes and gives you an opportunity to perform any business logic before a value is about to change, like setting an `isSelected` flag to false.

### ----------

Note, this next part is just some considerations I went through and extra information.  The above is an adequate solution but for those who want to know more, read on...

### ----------

Another approach is to make `selectedFamily` a read/write computed with a private observable backing like this:

```
var _selectedFamily = ko.observable();
self.selectedFamily = ko.computed({
    read: _selectedFamily,
    write: function (newValue) {
        var oldValue = _selectedFamily();
        if (oldValue) {
            oldValue.isSelected(false);
        }
        if (newValue) {
           newValue.isSelected(true);
        }
        _selectedFamily(newValue);
    }
});
```

How I have this set up isn't bullet proof but should give you an idea of the concept here.  This isn't a bad approach, and is one I'd go with if I had a need to make a decision based on the current and next value that would determine the outcome of setting the computed's result.  But in this situation, I'm not a fan of setting the `isSelected` flag in here because it has no bearing on the resulting value.  Assuming there was a need to create a computed to house logic that determined the outcome of the value that gets set, I would still opt with the subscriptions solution, as previously described, but on the privately backed `_selectedFamily` observable, in the off chance that there's a need to set the privately back observable's value without going through the computed.

---

The other piece I've addressed in the code is the click bindings on the buttons.  I wrapped them in a `with` binding.  Bindings that are bound to functions have the object of the current context passed into them by default.  Now instead of having to do this:

```
self.addChild = function () {
    var selectedFamily = self.selectedFamily();
    // ...code...
};
```

You can do:

```
self.addChild = function (selectedFamily) {
};
```

---

I've also moved the `<span data-bind="visible: isSelected">| Selected!</span>` binding out of the children context and into the family context as I think this is what was intended.  It seemed weird that you'd have the '| isSelected' text beside each child rather than the family name, but, if you wanted it by each child, you could do:

```
<li data-bind="text: fullName"><span data-bind="visible: $parent.isSelected">| Selected!</span></li>
```

---

One last feature about the KO `foreach` binding is binding with an object that has data/as properties.  It can make your markup more human readable and really helps with accessing parent chains.  Let's say we did want to use the family's `isSelected` flag to display something by the children's names.  Above we have to reference using `$parent`.  In some situations, you have multiple nested `foreach` bindings and you may find yourself writing things like `<span data-bind="text: $parents[2].name"></span>` which gives little information about the context you're trying to reference.  Using this method, you could instead write:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: $root.families, as: 'family' }">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: $family.children, as: 'child }>
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: child.firstName">
            <span data-bind="text: family.name">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In this way, you wouldn't even need a computed to write out the first and lastName.  I would use this method when I think I'm going to have a complex nested context binding structure and/or when I want to make a simple nested structure seem more human readable.

http://jsfiddle.net/34ZjB/1/

Comment: Thank you! Very thorough. And nice tip on the `with` binding. That makes the called function more meaningful. Same with using `as` on `foreach`. Meaningful context is really useful, especially as the markup gets larger. And regarding the `| Selected!` on each child, it is strange in this example, and was admittedly contrived, as my real scenario does require the "child" to have access to the property in question.

Comment: Another possibility: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html

Answer (score 2):

Check my comments, as I think they will help you a bit.

I made some changes to your fiddle.  I didn't quite understand why you included underscore as it was not needed to bind the events.  Also, your childViewModel and familyViewModel's were both actually just models.  The isSelected property on the family was just an extra binding that meant each time you changed the selectedFamily you had to go out and do additional updates.  Last, if you want to reset the children for the selectedFamily only, just remove the ko.utils.arrayForEach function and just do selectedFamily().children([]);  I am not sure why you would want to only reset the selected families children but it is pretty easy to do.

Needs code -

```
 var addChild = function () {
      self.selectedFamily().push(new childModel(self.selectedFamily().name());
 };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xhzkC/2/

Comment: I had the same confusions.  I think the isSelected was for the family, not the children.  It's not needed, but if someone wanted it in conjunction with setting the selected observable directly in the select's value binding, they could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/34ZjB/

Comment: I left the _.bind() stuff in there from my local test code, and it was convenient to use _.each() (I forgot about ko.utils' version). Admittedly this is a contrived example. I'll look through your changes now. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, certainly your changes make it work. I probably should have been clearer, though, that in my non-contrived, more complex app, I actually perform calculations on the dependencies, so I can't push that logic out to the view. (It's a drop-down with dates and I have to do date calculations on the current value.)

Comment: @Dennis, so the isSelected does need to be on the Child since that's the object that gets thrown away/recreated. Yeah, contrived, I know. And subscribing and then setting the isSelected is something I tried but it seemed to create the same sort of dependency. Actually, I don't think I tried it in this smaller example. I'll have to give that a shot.

Comment: Sure enough, subscribing and pushing the isSelected() change works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/cygnl7/xhzkC/5/ @Dennis, if you want to make it into an answer I'll accept it. It's just unfortunate that I can't use the automatic dependencies of passing an observable in (like in the original jsfiddle I posted) and clean that up somehow, because this is more "wiring" code I'd rather not do. But it works!

Comment: You shouldn't have to have an isSelected property nor subscribe to it in the parent view model.  Just having a single observable in the pageviewmodel for selected should do what you wamt

Comment: In this situation, minus the binding that shows the "| Selected!" text, I'd agree, the `isSelected` property is redundant.  But if there was other logic in the view to show (`visible`) or render (`if`) HTML, based on the currently selected family, one might start putting comparison logic in their binding or create computeds that loop through the families, comparing names or id properties with the selectedFamily in order to determine this.  Maintaining an `isSelected` flag is an easy way to do this.

Comment: What you are describing is a personal preference.  Op can easily pass that observable to other view models, which is what observables are for.  Or even better could create a computed on the other view model to watch back instead of having a bunch of observables being passed around.

Comment: It's certainly a preference thing. To me, passing an observable to create a computed feels kind of icky.  In this scenario, unless there's some other need for the Child to have access to the Family's `isSelected` observable, it's not necessary since you can access it in the HTML context: `<div data-bind="foreach: families"><div data-bind="foreach: children"><span data-bind="visible: $parent.isSelected">| Selected!</span></div></div>`

Comment: Passing the observable to other viewmodels is precisely what I was doing before posting this question. But that's what caused the memory leaks. When the children are removed, because they had access to the passed-in observable, which in turn created a reverse dependency inside ko, they don't get garbage collected.