# How to access parent from computed bind

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observable variable 'rate' and observable array 'seats' in view model. There is a computed variable in array's element 'priceOtherCurrency', which need a parent's 'rate' in its body. How can I access a parent variable or pass a parameter to the computed function?

Here is an example:

[Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/12153/)

In this example I added a 'rate' in the SeatReservation object:

```
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal, rate) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
    self.rate = rate;
    self.priceOtherCurrency = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.meal().price * self.rate();    
    }, this);
}
```

But it's duplicated. How can I do the same without 'rate' in SeatReservation, hidden field and so on?

Comment: I have found an answer. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640748/how-can-i-use-knockouts-parent-root-pseudovariables-from-inside-a-computed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access the parent binding context, and do this in the view:

```
<td data-bind="text: $parent.rate() * priceOtherCurrency()"></td>
```

and this in the viewmodel:

```
self.priceOtherCurrency = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.meal().price; 
}, this);
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/12156/

However, that puts business logic inside the view, which is not a good thing. The viewmodel hierarchy should mimic the conceptual hierarchy of you data structures. If the current viewmodels are the correct design for your data structures, I would say to leave them as they are, even if you have to pass the rate parameter in the constructor.